# Python unit tests fail when run together but passed when run individually

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, boto3

I've discovered very strange behavior. My tests fail when I run them together. First always pass, but second fails. Doesn't matter in which order I will put them in the code. In the second test response from mocked function is always MagicMock object which is the cause of whole test failing. I tried mock.mock_reset(), but it didn't help. Any ideas what is wrong here?

```
import copy
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, ANY
import boto3
import os
import test_constants as constants
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from constants import CW_QUERY


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials, to ensure we're not touching AWS directly"""
    os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'testing'


@patch("boto3.client")
def test_get_sftp_user_details(mock_boto_client):
    from transfer_cli import get_sftp_user_details

    mock_boto_client = mock_boto_client.return_value
    mock_boto_client.describe_user.return_value = constants.T_RESPONSE_DESCRIBE_USER
    result = get_sftp_user_details(constants.SFTP_SERVER_ID, constants.USER_NAME)

    assert result == constants.T_RESPONSE_DESCRIBE_USER


@patch("boto3.client")
def test_get_transfer_users(mock_boto_client):
    from transfer_cli import get_transfer_users

    mock_boto_client = mock_boto_client.return_value
    mock_boto_client.list_users.return_value = constants.T_RESPONSE_LIST_USERS
    result = get_transfer_users(constants.SFTP_SERVER_ID)

    assert result == constants.T_RESPONSE_LIST_USERS["Users"]
```

Comment: boto3.client is defined globaly in transfer_cli package.

Comment: Sorry could you add some details to the error which you have found? It could be useful for me too. If you can add a complete answer to your question.